# How to concatenate a CMD if certain attributes exists

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use bash script to "build" a command which will run if the object I am trying to find contains one or more attributes.
I have object which all have different attributes, some because they've been modified already.

**Goal:** Build a CMD if a object has certain attributes, and if none of these are present don't build/run CMD.

Example:

I can get information about my groups by running a command which takes a single group name, so I have gathered my groups in a list which a can use `for`-loop:

```
groups=$(exe group-find)

for i in ${groups[@]}; do
  exe grp-show --raw --all "$i"
done

  object: a
  attr: nested
  attr: groupattr

  object: b
  attr: nested
  attr: groupattr
  attr: groupManaged
  attr: groupObject

  object: c
  Id: XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX
  attr: nested
  attr: groupattr
  attr: groupManaged
  attr: groupObject

  object: d
  Id: XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX
  attr: nested
  attr: groupattr
  attr: groupObject
  attr: special
  attr: to-be-removed
```

I can modify my groups by running `exe grp_mod d --delete=attr=to-be-removed --delete=Id=XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX`.

The attributes I want to be removed is:

- Id: XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX
- attr: groupObject
- attr: special
- attr: to-be-removed

This means when the script runs if will basically skip `object: a` since we're not interesting in modifying it.

The other thing is that we need to transform attributes from `attr: XXXX` format to `attr=XXXX` in order for the `--delete=` option to be valid. E.g:

`--delete=attr=special` (**Valid**)
`--delete=attr: special` (**Not valid**)

This means we need to get the `Id` kinda dynamically as-we-go:
`grp_id=$(grp_info | grep Id | sed 's/: /=/g')`

**What I've tried (pseudo):**

```
#!/bin/bash

groups=$(exe group-find)

for i in ${groups[@]}; do
  cmd="exe grp_mod $i"
  grp_info=$(exe grp-show --raw --all "$i")

  attr_groupManaged=$(grp_info | grep groupManaged)
  if [ attr_groupManaged exists ]; then
    cmd+=" --delete=attr=groupManaged"
  fi


  Id=$(grp_info | grep Id | sed 's/: /=/g')
  if [ "$Id" ]; then
    cmd+=" --delete=$Id"
  fi
...
...

run cmd
done
```

Reason I'm asking this question is because I want to learn, and to know if it's another way of doing this can a bunch of if-statements that it seems like I'll end up with.
For example: Could it be possible to skip the current group before going through every if-statement, if it turns out it doens't have any attribute we're interested in, but rather check this when we receive group information (`grp_info`)

**EDIT:**
Current solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

groups=$(exe group-find)

for i in ${groups[@]}; do
  cmd="exe grp_mod $i"
  grp_info=$(exe grp-show --raw --all "$i")
  id=$(grp_info | grep Id | sed 's/: /=/g')

  if [[ -n "$id" ]]; then
          cmd+=" --delete=$id"
  fi

  if [[ $grp_data =~ "groupObject" ]]; then
          cmd+=" --delete=attr=groupObject"
  fi

  if [[ $grp_data =~ "special" ]]; then
          cmd+=" --delete=attr=special"
  fi

  if [[ $grp_data =~ "to-be-removed" ]]; then
          cmd+=" --delete=attr=to-be-removed"
  fi

  if [[ $cmd =~ "--delete" ]]; then
    $cmd
  fi
```

Highly appreciated if anyone knows a "better" solution.

Comment: `for $i in $groups;` should give you a syntax error. How did you ever get the program running?

Comment: Ok. I'll modify. But as pointed out it's pseudo. I'll add [@]...

Comment: `cmd+="--delete=attr=groupManaged"` adds the parameter without a separating space, so `exe` won't see it as separated parameter.

Comment: It would be clearer and less error prone, if you would turn `cmd` into an array. The first array element would then be the command to execute, and each following element would be an argument to this command.

Comment: I'm aware. I'll fix the typo.

Comment: `for $i in ${groups[@]}` should also give you a syntax error, but since you see it as pseudo code, I admit that you shouldn't worry about this now.

Comment: If you're refering to the variable not being defined, I'll make sure to add it. To soothe the minds of SO.

Comment: No, the syntax is wrong. After `for` must me a variable **name**, and `$i` is not a vailid name.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (*I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with the `exe` program you are using.

Please read [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), especially [this one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Still, here's an effort based on your pseudocode. Hope it helps.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r group
do args=( $(sed -En '/Id|groupObject|special|to-be-removed/{ 
                       s/^[[:space:]]*([^:]+):[[:space:]]+/--delete=\1=/; p; 
                     }' < <(exe grp-show --raw --all "$group") ) )
   ((${#args[@]})) && exe grp_mod "$group" "${args[@]}"
done < <( exe group-find )
```

The general logic -

Apparently `exe group-find` returns a list of keys you can use to look up each group. The `while` loop reads them one at a time.

If I understood your examples, `exe grp-show --raw --all "$group"` will output the data for one group as a block of lines formatted similar to what you showed.

`sed -En '...' < <(exe grp-show --raw --all "$group")` will process the `exe`'s output for one `$group` as its input using `E`xtended pattern matching (to reduce noise in the pattern), and create `n`o output unless explicitly requested in the program.

The program:
`/Id|groupObject|special|to-be-removed/{...}` says *on lines matching these strings*, and opens the `{` to allow multiple commands till the matching `}`.
`s/^[[:space:]]*([^:]+):[[:space:]]+/--delete=\1=/` reformats the line as an `exe` argument.
`p` says since we found one, `p`rint it.

The resulting output is the needed arguments, *if there were any hits*. If there were none, there's no output and the `args=( )` assignment wrapping it will be empty.

`${#args[@]}` returns the number of elements in the `args` array. `((...))` evaluates that in a math context, so it's true (and returns a zero exit code) if `${#args[@]}` has any data elements, triggering the `&&` operator to execute the `exe grp_mod "$group" "${args[@]}"` (which uses those arguments) only if there was a hit.

My test program:

```
$: cat tst
#!/bin/bash
groups=( $'\n  object: a\n  attr: nested\n  attr: groupattr\n'
         $'\n  object: b\n  attr: nested\n  attr: groupattr\n  attr: groupManaged\n  attr: groupObject\n' "
  object: c
  Id: XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX
  attr: nested
  attr: groupattr
  attr: groupManaged
  attr: groupObject
" "
  object: d
  Id: XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX
  attr: nested
  attr: groupattr
  attr: groupObject
  attr: special
  attr: to-be-removed
" )
while read -r group                                          # simulate exe grp-find
do head -2 <<< "${groups[group]}"                            # show which item we are processing
   args=(                                                    # use an array
     $(sed -En '                                             # elems are lines of output
      /Id|groupObject|special|to-be-removed/{                # matching one of these keys
        s/^[[:space:]]*([^:]+):[[:space:]]+/--delete=\1=/;   # edited to valid arg syntax
        p;                                                   # printed only on match
      }' <<< "${groups[group]}" )                            # simulate exe grp-show --raw --all
   )
   ((${#args[@]})) && echo "exe grp_mod \"\$i\" ${args[@]}"  # show the command generated
done < <( printf "%s\n" 0 1 2 3 )                            # simulate exe grp-find
```

it's output:

```
$: ./tst

  object: a

  object: b
exe grp_mod "$i" --delete=attr=groupObject

  object: c
exe grp_mod "$i" --delete=Id=XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX --delete=attr=groupObject

  object: d
exe grp_mod "$i" --delete=Id=XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX --delete=attr=groupObject --delete=attr=special --delete=attr=to-be-removed
```

Good luck. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I hope none of your data fields have embedded spaces...

Comment: Wow. This is advanced. Hmm. It doesn't have any embedded spaces, that I'm aware of. How would we change this if this was the case?

Comment: NVM. It does, I have following `done < <( exe group-find ) | sed "s[[:space]]//g"`

Comment: For input? `done < <( exe group-find | sed "s/[[:space:]]//g" )` - inside the parentheses, but test it, be sure the result is what you want. If you meant for output, just fix your syntax.